# How to add Where condition to Include method in linq C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to extend the IQueryable interface to do the following:

Lets say I have this linq code:

```
_booksSet.Include(x => x.Author).Include(x => x.anotherProperty)
.Where(x => x.IsInvalid == false && 
x.Author.IsInvalid == false && 
x.anotherProperty.IsInvalid == false);
```

I want to convert it into this simple method:

```
_bookSet.IncludeValidRelations(x => x.Author, x => x.anotherProperty)
```

What I've managed to do so far is only `Include()` and apply the `Where()` condition only to the main entity, so `Book`:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeValidRelations<TEntity>(
this IQueryable<TEntity> entities,
params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> result = entities;

    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        result = result.Include(include);
    }

    // Assuming TEntity has "Invalidated" property
    var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
    var invalidatedProperty = entityType.GetProperty("Invalidated");

    if (invalidatedProperty != null)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
        var invalidatedExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, "Invalidated");

        // Adding a check for the main entity's invalidation
        var mainEntityCheck = Expression.NotEqual(
            invalidatedExpression,
            Expression.Constant(true)
        );

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(mainEntityCheck, parameter);

        result = result.Where(predicate);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm not figuring out how to apply `Where` to the other `Include()` as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) is available in EF Core 5 and later. The question itself is unclear because you're describing what you assume the solution would look like, not what the *real* question is. If you want to filter "valid" query results you probably need [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) instead of a filtered Include

Comment: @RandRandom the question's code is already generic. EF and expressions are already generic and already use interfaces. If you mean why not use a "repository" CRUD class, you'd be introducing a *bug*. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, a higher-level abstraction that the Data-Access-Objects people usually mean when they talk about "repositories"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm going to ne using the same Include functionality with the same `Invalidated` check throughout my codebase, but not in all cases, so I figured an extension would be a better approach.

Comment: Even more reason to use global query filters like `modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasQueryFilter(b => !b.Author.Invalidated);`. You don't have to use the same DbContext in the entire application. You can have different DbContexts meant for different use cases, with different configuration. You can have one that only returns "valid" objects and another, perhaps meant for administrators or advanced cases, that doesn't filter

Comment: If you use SQL Server a better option may be to use temporal tables, in which case the database ensures you always get valid objects *and* relations at any point in time